# beamer + bibTeX: error, 'no aux' found!

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibliographies

I'm trying to compile a `chs_2015.bib` file with BibTeX (editor's button corresponding to command `bibtex %`) before including it in the actual Beamer *.tex presentation but I keep getting this error msg: `I couldn't open file name 'chs_2015.aux' Process exited with error(s)`. I've also tried to compile it with `pdfLaTeX` but then it says `No Log file found!`

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I'm supposed to work the *.bib file with `bibtex` then `pdfLaTeX`×2, right?

The *.bib file has only one entry (there were others, I slimmed it down to figure out what the problem was):

```
@article{akyildiz:2011,
author = {Akyildiz, Ian F. and Jornet, Josep Miquel and Pierobon, Massimiliano},
title = {Nanonetworks: A New Frontier in Communications},
journal = {Communications of the ACM},
year = {2011},
doi = {10.1145/2018396.2018417}
}
```

Here's a MWE of the *.tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}

\title{Le Maree}
%\subtitle{ }
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute[UniR5]{Università di Rimini}
\date{1 aprile 2034}


\begin{document}

%quadro1
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

%quadro2
\section{Introduzione}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Cos'è}
Interazione tra 
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Terra come illustrato in \cite{akyildiz:2011}
\item Luna
\item Sole
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
 \bibliographystyle{plain}
 \bibliography{chs_2015}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

**EDIT2:**
[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate to [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes to the original code and now the pdf is being made, though some warnings still exist.

In the preamble I've included

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{chs_2015}
```

('numeric' style makes no difference at all in a Beamer presentation!)

In the last frame of the presentation I've written this

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

Then I've changed the compiling command from `bibtex %` to `biber %`.

Finally I did as advised by @clspace i.e. run `pdflatex`, then `biber`, then again `pdflatex` twice on the master *.tex file.

Answer (score 1):

You should first compile the .tex with pdfLaTeX once, to produce a .aux file. Then compile the created .aux file with bibtex to create a .bbl from the .bib and finaly compile the .tex twice. This should work

Comment: Help! I've tried compiling the *.tex file but I'm getting a dozen errors plus some warnings including "No backend detected, using biber backend", "no polyglossia" and something about "csquotes". Can you help me out, here, please? I've uploaded a screenshot above, under my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me **if** I load `natbib` instead of `bibtex`. Is this acceptable?

Result:

[image: Brackets][image: sources]

Comment: You mean `\usepackage{natbib}` instead of `\usepackage{biblatex}`? Or is a whole different command/script that runs on the *.tex file?

Comment: @WobblyWindows exactly as you said, just replace the lines.

Comment: so the command remains `bibtex %` or can I switch to `biber %`? I'm asking this because in the meantime, I've changed the command to `biber %`. Also, is `natbib` the reason why you get '[1]' for the first reference source? At the moment, using `backend=biber, style=numeric` with package `biblatex`, I can't get **[1]** but the picture of a newspaper. Why is it so?

Comment: @WobblyWindows I don't quite understand what you're trying to say, but `biber` can only be used with bibtex. As for **[1]**, with natbib you can change to for example **(1)** by using `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`, or you can use the author and year by using `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`. What do you mean with a picture of a newspaper?

Comment: I suppose that `\usepackage[…]{natbib}` doesn't need `biber` as a backend the way `biblatex` does. Anyways, that's settled. As to the **[1]**, please see 'EDIT2' in my question above for a screenshot of what I mean with "picture of a newspaper".